# syncing files with aws s3 sync that have a minimum timestamp

Tags: amazon-s3

I am syncing a directory to an s3 bucket.  It is a directory, so I only want it to check for files that were created/updated in the last 24 hours.

With GNU/Linux's rsync, you might do this by piping the output of 'find -mtime' to rsync; I'm wondering if anything like this is possible with aws s3 sync?

Edited to show final goal: I'm running a script that constantly syncs files to S3 from a web server.  It runs every minute, first checks if there is already a process running (and exits if it does), then runs the aws sync command.  The sync command takes about 5 minutes to run and usually gets 3-5 new files.  This causes a slight load on the system, and I think if I just checked for files in the last 24 hours, it'd be much much faster.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? There might be an alternative way to achieve your goal. (Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.)

Comment: @John Rotenstein edited to show final goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command does *not* have an option to only include files created within a defined time period.

See: [aws s3 sync documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

It sounds like most of your time is being consumed by the check of whether files need to be updated. Some options:

- If you don't need all the files locally, you could delete them after some time (48 hours?). This means less files will need to be compared. By default, `aws s3 sync` will not delete destination files that do not match a local file (but this can be configured via a flag).
- You could copy recent files (past 24 hours?) into a different directory and run `aws s3 sync` from that directory. Then, clear out those files after a successful sync run.
- If you have flexibility over the filenames, you could include the date in the filename (eg `2018-03-13-foo.txt`) and then use `--include` and `--exclude` parameters to only copy files with desired prefixes.

Comment: actually, all our files are saved in a directory structure that uses a unix timestamp!